# Do you hyphenate a number with an omitted “hundred”?

Tags: hyphenation, numbers

Numbers with hundreds are normally spelled out without hyphens; *e.g.*, 250 = “two hundred and fifty”. But when informally spoken as “two fifty”(*), such as in dialogue, should this be hyphenated as “two-fifty”? What if the number already includes a hyphen, such as 255 – is that “two fifty-five” or “two-fifty-five”?

—
(*) This question assumes the context makes it clear this refers to 250 and not 2.50, such as in, “The subscription costs about two hundred a year, maybe two fifty.”

Comment: What's the context: screenplay, poetry, fiction, text explaining how people pronounce numbers...?

Comment: @StuartF In this case, creative fiction.

Comment: I was taught in junior high math that "Two hundred **and**  fifty" formally means 200.50 or $200.50 (as on a check), whereas "two hundred fifty" is  250 or $250.  Maybe I was taughted bad.

Comment: Examples both with and without the hyphen (two fifty / two-fifty; three fifty / three-fifty ...) can be found on the internet. It doesn't matter as long as the meaning is clear (say $250 as opposed to $2.50).

Comment: @DjinTonic Totally different in the UK, where 250 (/£250 / $250 /...) is read as (and spelled out) 'two hundred and fifty' rather than 'two hundred fifty'. The abbreviated form is, however, similarly 'two fifty'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When writing [the amount of a check in words](https://www.huntington.com/learn/checking-basics/how-to-write-a-check) (e.g. $130.45) in the U.S., you wouldn't write "one hundred **and** thirty and 45/100" before the printed word "dollars." ["And" Replaces the Decimal Point](https://www.thebalancemoney.com/write-numbers-using-words-4083198)

Comment: In creative fiction you can be creative. You could even write it as one word if you like, "twofifty" or "twofiftyfive" --  or "threefitty" if your character is a rapper.

Comment: @TimR: I disagree. Unless you're specifically trying to reproduce a character's elided pronunciation with something like "threefitty", the "creative" in "creative fiction" is not a license to ignore spelling rules wholesale. Remember that those rules exist to make your *readers'* lives easier.

Comment: What is the context of the sentence? What is the sentence? Why don't people get this? Single words can be pretty meaningless without context.

Comment: @Marthaª Too bad you weren't around to set him on the right path when Joyce was writing *Finnegan's Wake*.

Comment: @DjinnTonic You'd surely never say 'One hundred dollars and forty-five'. And decimal quantities do not sit well with mixed units (*'one hundred dollars point 45 cents').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sure I do--unless I catch myself in time and avoid it ;)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, *my* seventh grade math teacher trained us all to never say things like "point 45 cents" by telling a story of seeing a sign for "Apples - .50 cents", and proceeding to give the cashier a penny and telling her to keep the change. :)

Comment: @Martha In maths, it was considered better to work in pure numbers (taking care to first render say 3h 45 min as 3.75 working in hours) than to add say cm⁻¹ to a length to achieve a pure number from a measure, as was the practice in physics lessons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a short combination of words for the cited context that are common enough to generate an actual *usage chart* in Google NGrams (which *does* distinguish hyphenated usages from "two-word" usages).

But it's easy enough to search Google *Books*, which ignores punctuation marks anyway, so searching for...

> [*for **one fifty** each*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for%20one-fifty%20each%22)

...returns all instances *with and without* the hyphen. And looking at the first couple of pages (20 results in total) I see there are just ***two*** instances without the hyphen. My advice is to go with the vast majority, and include the hyphen.

Personally, I don't think it makes any difference at all whether ***one-fifty*** means *one hundred and fifty* or *one dollar and fifty cents / one pound and fifty pence*. But feasibly some people think different on that score.

Comment: Thank you for the research. I knew there likely wasn’t any kind of hard rule about it, but I was interested in seeing what the convention was, if any, and the fact that the vast majority of writers apparently choose to hyphenate it is good enough for me. I was mostly concerned with whether or not including or omitting the hyphen might blur the distinction between “250” and “2.50”, but I suppose it’s up to the writer to make it clear from context which is meant.

Comment: "I don't think it makes any difference at all whether one-fifty means one hundred and fifty or one dollar and fifty cents / one pound and fifty pence." But it can also mean one hundred and fifty pounds, and context won't always disambiguate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Situations where someone doesn't know whether something might cost £1.50 or £150 (or £150K, why not?) aren't likely to be common or interesting or lead to a sale!

Comment: I've seen similar examples on Antiques for Amateurs or programs with similar names.